# How to detect search provider which has already been added?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a feature like whenever a user comes to my site, I have added an option to add default search provider in their browser. I have written a code like this for Firefox -

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

    if (isFirefox === false) {
        $("#set-susper-default").remove();
        $(".input-group-btn").addClass("align-search-btn");
        $("#navbar-search").addClass("align-navsearch-btn");
    }

    if (window.external && window.external.IsSearchProviderInstalled) {
        var isInstalled = window.external.IsSearchProviderInstalled("http://susper.com");

        if (!isInstalled) {
            $("#set-susper-default").show();
        }
    }

    $("#install-susper").on("click", function () {
        window.external.AddSearchProvider("http://susper.com/susper.xml");
    });

    $("#cancel-installation").on("click", function () {
        $("#set-susper-default").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

User clicks on the install button and script runs and the site is added in search provider list. If a user refreshes or again comes to my site, this feature again come. How should I detect it is already added so that whenever a user comes to my site next time it does not appear.

It would be great help if someone can help me out. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean `IsSearchProviderInstalled` always returns `false`?

Comment: Yes @Halcyon :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can’t use `IsSearchProviderInstalled` and `AddSearchProvider`. They are considered no-ops in Chrome, and should do nothing as HTML Standard describes, more info here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5672001305837568. For now `AddSearchProvider` works in Firefox, but `IsSearchProviderInstalled` will return always 0. You can try it by going to https://google.com and adding this code: `external.IsSearchProviderInstalled("https://www.google.com");` in the console.

Instead you should try adding search plugin autodiscovery into your webpage. To do so just add the `<link>` element to the `<head>`:

```
<link rel="search"
      type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
      title="searchTitle"
      href="pluginURL">
```

More info about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox#Autodiscovery_of_search_plugins